# Problem with calling def function and subtracting two dates in days

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a basic program in python which takes in the user's input on their birthdate, and tells the user back how many days old they are, and how many days are left till their next birthday.
What I basically need help with is if you'd show me how to have the "birthday" function give the desired result or how I can extract the days from the "time" function's result delta.
Sorry the code's a mess

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
def time(date, month, year):
    bdate = datetime(year, month, date)
    delta = datetime.now() - bdate
    return delta
def birthday(year, month, date):
    d0 = date.today()
    d1 = date(year, month, date)
    d2 = d0 - d1
    return d2.days
a = int(input ("Enter the year in which you were born: "))
b = int(input("Enter the month(in number) in which you were born: "))
c = int(input("Enter the date in which you were born: "))
print(time(c, b, a))
print(birthday(a, b, c))
```

I expected this code to return d2.days which was how many days have happened between the day the user was born and today as I was unable to figure out a way to extract that from the successful "time" def

These are the errors I've been shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "  ", line 16, in <module>
print(birthday(a, b, c))
File "  ", line 8, in birthday
d0 = date.today()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Comment: You are shadowing the name `date` (from the `datetime` module) by using another name `date` as parameter for `birthday`. If you use `date` inside `birthday` it refers to the parameter, not the imported name from `datetime`. Simply use a different name than `date` for the third parameter of `birthday`.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is was so confusing I couldn't even figure out what I was doing wrong :P